# Sorting Arraylist using Bubblesort in parallel with fork/join pool

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, forkjoinpool

So what I am trying to do is sort an ArrayList using Fork/Join pool. The algorithm that I will use to sort doesn't matter: I just choosed a random one for here. What matters is how I am supposed to use the Recursive task with fork/join pool so that the ArrayList will keep on splitting until the ArrayList size reaches a certain number (like 1000) then it will perform the sorting and then it will join back into one ArrayList. 
Here is my code:

assignment5

```
public class assignment5 {

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
//lets say this arraylist is full with random numbers

    public void run(){

        Instant start = Instant.now();

        MyRecursiveTask myRecursiveTask = new MyRecursiveTask(numbers);
        ArrayList<Integer> mergedResult = ForkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveTask);

        Instant end = Instant.now();

        Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);
        System.out.println("Seconds: " + duration.getSeconds());

    }

}
```

over here in assignment5 gives me error on
`ForkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveTask);`
it says non static method invoke connot be reffereced from a static content

MyRecursiveTask

```
    private List<Integer> numbers;

    protected List<Integer> compute() {
        //numbers here is the same as in assignment 5
        //if work is above threshold, break tasks up into smaller tasks
        if(this.numbers.size() > 1000) {
            System.out.println("Splitting workLoad : " + this.numbers.size());

            List<MyRecursiveTask> subtasks = new ArrayList<MyRecursiveTask>();
            subtasks.addAll(createSubtasks());

            for(MyRecursiveTask subtask : subtasks){
                subtask.fork();
            }

            for(MyRecursiveTask subtask : subtasks) {
                subtask.join();
            }
            return numbers;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Doing workLoad myself: " + this.numbers.size());
            bubbleSort(numbers);
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    private List<MyRecursiveTask> createSubtasks() {
        List<MyRecursiveTask> subtasks = new ArrayList<MyRecursiveTask>();

        List<Integer> list1 = numbers.subList(0,numbers.size()/2);
        List<Integer> list2 = numbers.subList(numbers.size()/2, numbers.size());

        MyRecursiveTask subtask1 = new MyRecursiveTask(list1);
        MyRecursiveTask subtask2 = new MyRecursiveTask(list2);

        subtasks.add(subtask1);
        subtasks.add(subtask2);

        return subtasks;
    }
    public void bubbleSort(List<Integer> numbers){//bubble sort alg here}
}
```

Comment: _"over here on invoke it gives me error"_ - If you're getting an error, please include details about that error in your question.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: And hint: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java ... you **absolutely** do not want to have any **print** statements happening when measuring performance. These prints are "pretty" expensive, and can greatly vary in duration. It might be a good idea to somehow "use" the result of that operation (so: printing it), but that should happen **after** you acquired that second timestamp!

Answer (score 0):

[ForkJoinPool.invoke()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#invoke-java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask-) is **not** a static method, but you are using as it was.

You need to create an instance of `ForkJoinPool` and call the `invoke` of that instance.
Also you will need an explicit cast to make things work as you wanted (about that `ArrayList`).

Replace the line that gives you *"error"* with these ones and it'll work!

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();
ArrayList<Integer> mergedResult = (ArrayList<Integer>) forkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveTask);
```

Hope I helped!

*PS: If you haven't done it already, I invite you to read the comments of the other users, you may find them helpful.*